# Why am I getting error 400 from fcm.googleapis.com?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating my project from legacy FCM API to HTTP v1. Everything used to work fine, but now I am gettin always Bad Request error, code 400.
I am using thic c# code to send push notifications:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\...\\authentication.json"));

    var notif = new
    {
        message = new
        {
            token = "99Jsk5sA.......(device's token)",
            notification = new
            {
                title = "Test V1",
                body = "This is test"
            }
        }
    };

    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(notif);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project_name123/messages:send", content);


    MessageBox.Show(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

- my_project_name123 is replaced with valid project name
- Google Cloud Service Account for FCM is created and enabled
- Key is active
- API (V1) in Firebase settings is enabled
- Device's token is valid
  I am stuck at this point for a very long time. Any help please?

Comment: Is the `Authorization` header valid? You are reading the contents from a file. What is the contents of that file?

Comment: JSON file in authorization header is file downloaded from Google Cloud → Service Accounts → Keys. Before I used key itself (looking like AA9916fcf9bc......) but it always returned error 401 unauthorized. For now, with JSON file am getting bad request. So I think authorization header is valid.

Comment: A service account JSON key is not a valid Authorization header. Do not assume, what is the header?

Comment: What is valid header then? When I use Key ID or OAuth 2 Client ID from Service Accounts in IAM & Admin, the both returns 401 UNAUTHENTICATED.

Comment: The value must be an OAuth2 Access Token.

Comment: Yes, but how to get it?

Comment: There are many ways. The Google SDKs handle authorization. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct) might help.

Comment: Read this link also: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account